# RSA finding p and q with pka

Tags: python, rsa, prime-factoring

I have this exercise:

> Exercice 9 : ( Common RSA primes )
> Alice and Bob have generated a set of RSA modules together. Your goel is to find the prime numbers p and q they used to generate these modules, available in the files pk_alice and pk_bob.
> there is the pka_alice:
>
> 93145558017597242451057840020003423492065036505715635939073421584870064178836557007438920905568366141278155363295217244442270120551665563816731464612225841456174904661719015967457696683736586858513914335501922092345895701281682242489324726462415020945038049322877151602626496388802926568113827098181488546541
>
> pka_bob:
> 130627775975870619265103967461863569685393719623259606834494161761353696231137838485596006850409649916631767658717771142397327842476766835551088514711108732237134464583834085414090472465465656901718533120526240047672780456483182231171430047581628792398849389571220237028177673312592572286345009761324975840273

I tried this python program but it takes forever (never get an output from it):

```
import sympy

def factorize(n):
    factors = sympy.ntheory.factorint(n)
    
    # Les clés du dictionnaire factors contiennent les facteurs premiers et les valeurs correspondent à leurs exposants.
    # Si n est le produit de deux nombres premiers, il y aura deux clés avec des exposants de 1.
    prime_factors = [factor for factor in factors if factors[factor] == 1]

    if len(prime_factors) == 2:
        p, q = prime_factors
        return p, q
    else:
        return None, None  # La factorisation a échoué

# Remplacez n par la valeur de n que vous souhaitez factoriser
n = 130627775975870619265103967461863569685393719623259606834494161761353696231137838485596006850409649916631767658717771142397327842476766835551088514711108732237134464583834085414090472465465656901718533120526240047672780456483182231171430047581628792398849389571220237028177673312592572286345009761324975840273

p, q = factorize(n)

if p and q:
    print(f"Les facteurs premiers de {n} sont {p} et {q}")
else:
    print("La factorisation a échoué.")
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Alice:
p = 11546228166566908996944683360898685003804727870211092212733704895162284555816549530587425586574198315100684457091938790507073108514058962518074083478643487
q = 8067184943331379055883676674511286075021098911943040287647388643355051515709741724813022793998233351188112736071886443985753058022434276985771666457801843

Bob:
p = 11546228166566908996944683360898685003804727870211092212733704895162284555816549530587425586574198315100684457091938790507073108514058962518074083478643487
q = 11313458740934508371320688917048544848372493637810071784612124974863165934304508093282020336767731785955272382720056869761911762809833915572489801623030479
```

The hint is in the exercise title: "**Common** RSA primes".

```py
import math

a = 93145558017597242451057840020003423492065036505715635939073421584870064178836557007438920905568366141278155363295217244442270120551665563816731464612225841456174904661719015967457696683736586858513914335501922092345895701281682242489324726462415020945038049322877151602626496388802926568113827098181488546541
b = 130627775975870619265103967461863569685393719623259606834494161761353696231137838485596006850409649916631767658717771142397327842476766835551088514711108732237134464583834085414090472465465656901718533120526240047672780456483182231171430047581628792398849389571220237028177673312592572286345009761324975840273

g = math.gcd(a, b)
print(f'Alice:\np = {g}\nq = {a//g}\n')
print(f'Bob:\np = {g}\nq = {b//g}')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZI7blNhEIUlyrsKd04kIPN-IFHAOtLYgTiWEttEpkCIldCkgUVRsRTOCBAFlizde2f-M-d883_9fvp0vjsenp6-fTzfvqgfz37uH07Hx_PqYXO-W5bN6vWqlc3dizi9U0zMmTzLiISI1ESthcJJ8fdkD_XWpkSJvaySKIyzCg2OlzQtnGhyD3wLNpYsdtdQaRfGFPxEkljQxIFzocWR8BIWLCIQhq_gtCaDRnITe0eaZ3RAODGuoryctdlU3YlbMBiOvdpHHqIlE6paxVKgLsaOaG1IVGT4LpWIxUESaGhYqSJpCfhn1oLRLi62Krdw42ULcKwUkjnUHAyC5wCTjsfgAiX4LNdWeA9RgXuCb7M2RqBgBZGpYEaWgqRPC3qcjBpOGmgUnYmkyZjFjHV0Kngi0xQgiO0xwRob6nhCWTATgwIcFBMJvhmSBAITAMFgDhtn-NNZApJj4aMIaQJ4K2WQg7cE2yk5WIIU6HYVsA1hbIowi8A5cXa0vMUTSANLIOqJKTaIjCR1WZYd2M31e7m7eXexeb7aXi6nx_3hfHG7fnO_v3n_6vpwQsvn3Zfrw4d52FxdzfP6X9_b4_a_ru10rS9_X_Q_9_3vvf8F)